# Why can't pandas assign value after boolean index

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4],
...                    [5, 6, 7, 8],
...                    [9, 10, 11, 12],
...                    [13, 14, 15, 16]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> s = pd.Series([True, False, False], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df.loc[0, ['a', 'b']][s] = 100
>>> df
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
```

As you can see I was unable to assign 100 to the `(0, 'a')` element of `df`. What went wrong?

Comment: I suggest you look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/5763165

Comment: yes this was definitely helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First create `Series` by same length and same values like `df.columns` with filling `False` for not matched values and then pass instead `['a','b']`:

```
s = s.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)

df.loc[0, s] = 100
print (df)
     a   b   c   d
0  100   2   3   4
1    5   6   7   8
2    9  10  11  12
3   13  14  15  16
```

**Details**:

```
print (s)
a     True
b    False
c    False
d    False
dtype: bool
```